# IOS-Deploy and iOS developer certificate

Tags: ios

I am trying to bring the demo application of IOS-Deploy on my iPhone.

https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy

I followed the instructions on this page.

`make demo.app` works and generates the bundle.

The command `ios-deploy --debug --bundle demo.app` from the Makefile does however issue an error message aka "Could not verify app".

Deploying a self-made app with xCode works however. In this case I also get a notification on the IPhone that allows me to confirm the execution of the app.

Among others, I am unsure whether IOS-Deploy digests my Apple Developer Certificate correctly. I did not do anything specific to install it.

I need to use IOS-Deploy for a project, so I cannot just switch to xCode.